# How do I fetch the next page of results, by following the URI

Tags: ruby, api, soundcloud, partitioning

"The SoundCloud API will be dropping support for offset-based pagination on March 2, 2015, in favor of linked partitioning.

To page through a JSON response, pass the linked_partitioning=1 parameter along with your request and it will return a collection, along with a next_href property if there are additional results. To fetch the next page of results, simply follow that URI. If the response does not contain a next_href property, you have reached the end of the results."

I'm trying to do this in ruby with the soundcloud api. I know max results are 200, but if I search through 500 I will literally see "next_href" in the response. Is it possible to continue the search? How do I do it if its possible? 
When I try calling it, I end up getting a syntax error ":undefined method `title'" or just not the requested amount of results.

Answer (score 0):

When you request a collection of resources (eg: search results, stream tracks), if you don't get the full collection back again, in the response is a field called `next_href`. This is a url pointing to the next page of the same collection. Each subsequent page will give you a `next_href` until you reach the end and none will exist. As an example:

```
/users/2/tracks.json?limit=10

{
  "collection": [ { id: 123, title: ... }, { id: 456 ... }, ... ],
  "next_href": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/2/tracks.json?limit=10&offset=10"
}
```

I don't quite know what you mean here:

> When I try calling it, I end up getting a syntax error ":undefined method `title'" or just not the requested amount of results.

That sounds like a bug in your ruby code.

Comment: Ok, I see where that pops up in the response, so how would I get/call on the next amount of results using the next_href? ...or the linked partitioning in my ruby code?  
...As for the "When I try calling it, I end up getting a syntax error ":undefined method `title'" or just not the requested amount of results." part, i get that error when i include "tracks.each { |t| puts t.title }" in my code.
@nickf

Comment: I'm trying to make it so i can go to the next amount of results, maybe put somewhere in my code go to next_href when I get the first page of response.